# Wordpress slug duplicate content parent/child

Tags: wordpress, url-routing, slug

i need some advice what i´m doing wrong

So i have one Page without a parent page attribute called "bar" with slug "bar"

available at

```
/bar/
```

then i have child-pages for example "foo" which have the "bar" page as parent attribute and slug is "foo"

available at

```
/bar/foo/
```

but also at

```
/foo/
```

is this the standard-behaviour of wordpress ? 
do i have to make .htaccess rewrite-rules for every single page ? 
is there any option i need to check ?

i´m using wordpress 3.6.1

Answer (score 2):

You will find the 'rewrite rule generator' of wordpress in settings / permalinks.

However, if you need more customization, you can do it on a per page / article basis with the edit link located next to the permalink under the page title. Warning: this edit button is only available if you did not choose 'custom structure' in wordpress permalink settings.

If this solution is still limited for you, you can edit the .htaccess of your wordpress site to add your own rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard behavior of WordPress. Normally permalinks of sub pages contain the slug of its parent page just before the sub page slug. If we try to go for a permalink without the parent page slug it will redirect automatically to the permalink structure with parent page slug.

Comment: so do you have some information if this is a duplicate content problem? for my opinion when there is no crawlable link to /foo/ and all links are to /bar/foo/ the link "does not exist" ? or am i wrong

Comment: Actually the link /foo/(for example) is assigned to displaying posts and parent pages. Provided you must select Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > Post name. But if we create a parent page and post with same slug foo, WordPress give preference to parent page and it will display it. This is from my limited knowledge :-)

Comment: Is this really default behaviour? As I'm having duplicate title tags of URLs that include the parent in the slug, and that does not. How can I get rid of the URLs that do not include the parent? Or allow them to redirect to the URLs with the parent?